# Solving pde with initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have this problem

$v_t + xv_x = x v^2 $

With $v(t,1)=t^2$

My solution is

The initial curve is ($T,1,T^2)$ which hapoen when s = 0 and we have characteristic

$$dx/ds = x, dt/ds = 1, dv/ds = xv^2$$

Which i solved them to be

$$ x= e^s, t= s+T, u = \frac{ T^2+1- T^2 e^s }{T^2} $$

Now i just need to solve fot T and s and replace in u, correct¿ is my approach correct .?

Comment: I didn't check the integral for $v$, but the procedure is correct.  Now substitute the solution into the equation and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with your system of differential equations :
$$dx/ds = x, dt/ds = 1, dv/ds = xv^2$$
or on an equivalent form (Charpit-Lagrange) :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dv}{xv^2}=ds$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{x}$
$$t-\ln|x|=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dv}{xv^2}$
$$\frac{1}{v}+x=c_2$$
An implicit form of the general solution of the PDE is :
$$\frac{1}{v}+x=F(t-\ln|x|)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to the condition :

$v(t,1)=t^2\quad$ leading to $\quad\frac{1}{t^2}+1=F(t-\ln|1|)=F(t)$

So, the function $F(X)$ is determined : 
$$F(X)=\frac{1}{X^2}+1$$
We put it into the above general solution where $X=t-\ln|x|$
$$\frac{1}{v}+x=\frac{1}{ (t-\ln|x|)^2}+1$$
This is the particular solution (on implicit form) which satisfies the PDE and the boundary condition.

For the explicit solution, solve it for $v$ :
$$v(x,t)= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{(t-\ln|x|)^2}  +1-x}$$
$$v(x,t)= \frac{(t-\ln|x|)^2}{1+(1-x)(t-\ln|x|)^2 }$$